# Can someone post a program template for submitting a solution in Java in Codeforces programming competitions?

Tags: java

Yes I want to start programming competitions so I dont know how to submit in Java?

Answers very apreciated

bye

Comment: I'd suggest asking Codeforces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know about CF but you can try this at SPOJ. Have a look at examples [here](http://discuss.spoj.com/t/solution-to-test-in-java/59)

Answer (score 1):

i have been in a lot of contests:

```
/** @team=civilian */
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;

public class _template {
    static BufferedReader input;
    static StringTokenizer _stk;

    static String readln() throws IOException {
        String l = input.readLine();
        if (l != null)
            _stk = new StringTokenizer(l, " ");
        return l;
    }

    static String next() {
        return _stk.nextToken();
    }

    static int nextInt() {
        return Integer.parseInt(next());
    }

    static void dbg(Object... o) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(o));
    }

    static PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(System.out)));

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        // input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("_template"));
        // output.print("ja");
        // output.close();// Be sure to close the output at the end 
                        //or maybe he does not print everything.
    }
}
```

Some think is best to compite in c++:

```
//
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

#define D(x) cout << #x << " = " << (x) << endl;
#define REP(i,a,n) for(int i=(a); i<(int)(n); i++)
#define FOREACH(it,v) for(__typeof((v).begin()) it=(v).begin(); it!=(v).end(); ++it)
#define ALL(v) (v).begin(), (v).end()

using namespace std;

typedef long long int64;

const int INF = (int)(1e9);
const int64 INFLL = (int64)(1e18);
const double EPS = 1e-13;

int main() {
#ifdef LOCAL
    freopen(".in.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen(".out.txt", "w", stdout);
#else
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
#endif

}
```

and this help when you are practicing:

```
#createfiles.sh
function createfiles {
    cp path/_template.cpp ./"$1.cpp";
    touch "$1.in.txt";
    touch "$1.out.txt";
    sed "s/.in.txt/$1.in.txt/" < "$1.cpp" > "tmp";
    sed "s/.out.txt/$1.out.txt/" < "tmp" > "$1.cpp" ;
    rm tmp;
} 
createfiles $1
```

runing test:

```
#compile_cpp.sh
function compile_cpp {
    g++ -o "${1::-4}_exe" -DLOCAL "$1"; 
    ./"${1::-4}_exe";  
} 
compile_cpp $1
```

and you run it like this:

```
$ bash createfiles.sh uva12520
# you program an awesome solution
# and you test it
$ bash compile_ccp.sh uva12520.cpp
```

i think is best to create an alias in your .bash like
    alias compile_cpp_maraton='function fun() {  bash /path/my_commands/compile_cpp_maraton.sh "$1"; }; fun'

Sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a template mentioned in FlatFoot Codeforces user blog http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/7018

```
public class Main{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      MyScanner sc = new MyScanner();
      out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(System.out));

      // Start writing your solution here. -------------------------------------

      /*
      int n      = sc.nextInt();        // read input as integer
      long k     = sc.nextLong();       // read input as long
      double d   = sc.nextDouble();     // read input as double
      String str = sc.next();           // read input as String
      String s   = sc.nextLine();       // read whole line as String

      int result = 3*n;
      out.println(result);                    // print via PrintWriter
      */

      // Stop writing your solution here. -------------------------------------
      out.close();
   }



   //-----------PrintWriter for faster output---------------------------------
   public static PrintWriter out;

   //-----------MyScanner class for faster input----------
   public static class MyScanner {
      BufferedReader br;
      StringTokenizer st;

      public MyScanner() {
         br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      }

      String next() {
          while (st == null || !st.hasMoreElements()) {
              try {
                  st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
          return st.nextToken();
      }

      int nextInt() {
          return Integer.parseInt(next());
      }

      long nextLong() {
          return Long.parseLong(next());
      }

      double nextDouble() {
          return Double.parseDouble(next());
      }

      String nextLine(){
          String str = "";
      try {
         str = br.readLine();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return str;
      }

   }
   //--------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at it,you might find your answer here :

http://rgpv.ac.in/Campus/CodeForce%20Tutorial.pdf

**Java syntax** :

```
import java.util.*;

public class Prime {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int i;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    i = in.nextInt();
    /* Take input from standard input */
    if (isprime(i)) {
        System.out.println("YES");
        /*
         * Print outp ut on standard output
         */
    } else {
        System.out.println("NO");
        /* Print output on standard output */
    }
}

public static boolean isprime(int a) {
    for (int i = 2; i < a; i++) {
        if (a % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


/**
 * Author: o_panda_o
 * Email: emailofpanda@yahoo.com
 */
public class Main{

    static class ProblemSolver{
        public void solveTheProblem(InputReader in,OutputWriter out){
            /**
             * This template is used by many coders for fast IO
             *
             * This portion acts as the main method we use. Everything we need to code...
             * ...can be written here without even touching the main method.
             *
             * Following are the examples for IO and for more information have a look...
             * ...on the classes InputReader(for Fast Input) and OutputWriter(for Fast...
             * ...Output). The methods there are self explanatory
             */

            /**
             * How to take inputs:
             *  - Taking input is just nearly similar to the way we take input using scanner in Java.
             *  - e.g. int n=in.nextInt(); long n=in.nextLong();
             */

            /**
             * How to print output:
             *  - It is just like we use PrintWriter. Instead of using System.out, we can...
             *  ...only use out in that place.
             *  - e.g. out.print(), out.println() etc.
             */

        }
        //You can add necessary methods here also. Uncomment the code and test it above
        //public int add(int a,int b){
        //    return a+b;
        //}
    }
    //Everything below you see is a template for every code. You don't need to change them most of the time.
    //As you go on coding, in the time of need you will realise what you need to change when. Just trust me on this.
    public static void main(String[] args){
        InputStream inputStream=System.in;
        OutputStream outputStream=System.out;
        InputReader in=new InputReader(inputStream);
        OutputWriter out=new OutputWriter(outputStream);
        ProblemSolver problemSolver=new ProblemSolver();
        problemSolver.solveTheProblem(in,out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
}

class InputReader {
    private boolean finished = false;

    private InputStream stream;
    private byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    private int curChar;
    private int numChars;
    private SpaceCharFilter filter;

    public InputReader(InputStream stream) {
        this.stream = stream;
    }

    public int read() {
        if (numChars == -1) {
            throw new InputMismatchException();
        }
        if (curChar >= numChars) {
            curChar = 0;
            try {
                numChars = stream.read(buf);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new InputMismatchException();
            }
            if (numChars <= 0) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return buf[curChar++];
    }

    public int peek() {
        if (numChars == -1) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (curChar >= numChars) {
            curChar = 0;
            try {
                numChars = stream.read(buf);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (numChars <= 0) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return buf[curChar];
    }

    public int nextInt() {
        int c = read();
        while (isSpaceChar(c)) {
            c = read();
        }
        int sgn = 1;
        if (c == '-') {
            sgn = -1;
            c = read();
        }
        int res = 0;
        do {
            if (c < '0' || c > '9') {
                throw new InputMismatchException();
            }
            res *= 10;
            res += c - '0';
            c = read();
        } while (!isSpaceChar(c));
        return res * sgn;
    }

    public long nextLong() {
        int c = read();
        while (isSpaceChar(c)) {
            c = read();
        }
        int sgn = 1;
        if (c == '-') {
            sgn = -1;
            c = read();
        }
        long res = 0;
        do {
            if (c < '0' || c > '9') {
                throw new InputMismatchException();
            }
            res *= 10;
            res += c - '0';
            c = read();
        } while (!isSpaceChar(c));
        return res * sgn;
    }

    public String nextString() {
        int c = read();
        while (isSpaceChar(c)) {
            c = read();
        }
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        do {
            if (Character.isValidCodePoint(c)) {
                res.appendCodePoint(c);
            }
            c = read();
        } while (!isSpaceChar(c));
        return res.toString();
    }

    public boolean isSpaceChar(int c) {
        if (filter != null) {
            return filter.isSpaceChar(c);
        }
        return isWhitespace(c);
    }

    public static boolean isWhitespace(int c) {
        return c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\r' || c == '\t' || c == -1;
    }

    private String readLine0() {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        int c = read();
        while (c != '\n' && c != -1) {
            if (c != '\r') {
                buf.appendCodePoint(c);
            }
            c = read();
        }
        return buf.toString();
    }

    public String readLine() {
        String s = readLine0();
        while (s.trim().length() == 0) {
            s = readLine0();
        }
        return s;
    }

    public String readLine(boolean ignoreEmptyLines) {
        if (ignoreEmptyLines) {
            return readLine();
        } else {
            return readLine0();
        }
    }

    public BigInteger readBigInteger() {
        try {
            return new BigInteger(nextString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new InputMismatchException();
        }
    }

    public char nextCharacter() {
        int c = read();
        while (isSpaceChar(c)) {
            c = read();
        }
        return (char) c;
    }

    public double nextDouble() {
        int c = read();
        while (isSpaceChar(c)) {
            c = read();
        }
        int sgn = 1;
        if (c == '-') {
            sgn = -1;
            c = read();
        }
        double res = 0;
        while (!isSpaceChar(c) && c != '.') {
            if (c == 'e' || c == 'E') {
                return res * Math.pow(10, nextInt());
            }
            if (c < '0' || c > '9') {
                throw new InputMismatchException();
            }
            res *= 10;
            res += c - '0';
            c = read();
        }
        if (c == '.') {
            c = read();
            double m = 1;
            while (!isSpaceChar(c)) {
                if (c == 'e' || c == 'E') {
                    return res * Math.pow(10, nextInt());
                }
                if (c < '0' || c > '9') {
                    throw new InputMismatchException();
                }
                m /= 10;
                res += (c - '0') * m;
                c = read();
            }
        }
        return res * sgn;
    }

    public boolean isExhausted() {
        int value;
        while (isSpaceChar(value = peek()) && value != -1) {
            read();
        }
        return value == -1;
    }

    public String next() {
        return nextString();
    }

    public SpaceCharFilter getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }

    public void setFilter(SpaceCharFilter filter) {
        this.filter = filter;
    }

    public interface SpaceCharFilter {
        public boolean isSpaceChar(int ch);
    }
    public int[] nextIntArray(int n){
        int[] array=new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;++i)array[i]=nextInt();
        return array;
    }
    public int[] nextSortedIntArray(int n){
        int array[]=nextIntArray(n);
        Arrays.sort(array);
        return array;
    }
    public int[] nextSumIntArray(int n){
        int[] array=new int[n];
        array[0]=nextInt();
        for(int i=1;i<n;++i)array[i]=array[i-1]+nextInt();
        return array;
    }
    public long[] nextLongArray(int n){
        long[] array=new long[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;++i)array[i]=nextLong();
        return array;
    }
    public long[] nextSumLongArray(int n){
        long[] array=new long[n];
        array[0]=nextInt();
        for(int i=1;i<n;++i)array[i]=array[i-1]+nextInt();
        return array;
    }
    public long[] nextSortedLongArray(int n){
        long array[]=nextLongArray(n);
        Arrays.sort(array);
        return array;
    }
}

class OutputWriter {
    private final PrintWriter writer;

    public OutputWriter(OutputStream outputStream) {
        writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream)));
    }

    public OutputWriter(Writer writer) {
        this.writer = new PrintWriter(writer);
    }

    public void print(char[] array) {
        writer.print(array);
    }

    public void print(Object... objects) {
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
            if (i != 0) {
                writer.print(' ');
            }
            writer.print(objects[i]);
        }
    }

    public void print(int[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (i != 0) {
                writer.print(' ');
            }
            writer.print(array[i]);
        }
    }

    public void print(double[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (i != 0) {
                writer.print(' ');
            }
            writer.print(array[i]);
        }
    }

    public void print(long[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (i != 0) {
                writer.print(' ');
            }
            writer.print(array[i]);
        }
    }

    public void println(int[] array) {
        print(array);
        writer.println();
    }

    public void println(double[] array) {
        print(array);
        writer.println();
    }

    public void println(long[] array) {
        print(array);
        writer.println();
    }

    public void println() {
        writer.println();
    }

    public void println(Object... objects) {
        print(objects);
        writer.println();
    }

    public void print(char i) {
        writer.print(i);
    }

    public void println(char i) {
        writer.println(i);
    }

    public void println(char[] array) {
        writer.println(array);
    }

    public void printf(String format, Object... objects) {
        writer.printf(format, objects);
    }

    public void close() {
        writer.close();
    }

    public void flush() {
        writer.flush();
    }

    public void print(long i) {
        writer.print(i);
    }

    public void println(long i) {
        writer.println(i);
    }

    public void print(int i) {
        writer.print(i);
    }

    public void println(int i) {
        writer.println(i);
    }

    public void separateLines(int[] array) {
        for (int i : array) {
            println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't really answer the question

Comment: @pvkiran what about now. I've changes it a little bit. Anything else is unclear ?